# Open source alternative to excel for investment and portfolio calculations

Tags: software

I am a Linux user, and taking an investment and portfolio management course that uses excel. I was wondering if there are open source alternatives to excel for optimal portfolio calculations? If yes, are they used basically the same way as excel?

Comment: You know something, it looks absolutely dreadful when you [ask almost a thousand questions and basically provide no answers](http://quant.stackexchange.com/users/408/tim?tab=accounts). Did the immediate closure of your [last question](http://quant.stackexchange.com/q/1801/35) teach you nothing? I'm going to leave this one open just out of morbid curiosity for how the community responds.

Comment: @chris: I don't think your comment is appropriate. Your opinion on my answers/questions has nothing to do with this question. Your pointing to my previous question has nothing to do with this question either.

Comment: @tim The same arguments apply to your last question as to this question. But to state the obvious...

Comment: While I don't agree with @chrisaycock's tone (please be nicer to the newbies) your question is, unfortunately, off topic here. No self respecting quant uses excel to get work done, maybe they use it as a front emd for traders/PMs, but if you haven't used anything other than excel, you're probably not (yet) a quant. But please come back and ask questions once you have gained sufficient knowledge for your questions to be on-topic.

Comment: @Tal The real reason I hate this question (beyond the amateurish nature of it) is that the asker has refused to use what his course's instructor told him to use. Even worse, the OP didn't ask his instructor directly what an acceptable alternative would have been. The sheer arrogance from someone who doesn't know anything about the industry to presuppose that he can skirt his education is incredibly off-putting.

Comment: @chrisaycock those are all valid additional reasons to close this question (and maybe you should vote to close, as you'd be the fifth so it wouldn't be like your moderator privileges added anything), but there's just a nicer way to say these things sometimes.

Comment: Tim: if your instructor told you to use Excel, it is probably because you should learn Excel.  The open-source alternatives are very rarely used on Wall Street, so it is worth your while to learn the program if you intend to do "investment and portfolio management."

Comment: @chris: You are pretty much a person based your own reasoning on imagination. Look out your phrasing: "refused", "the sheer arrogance", "skirt his education" ... Where did you get all these? The strong hatred in your heart?

Comment: Can we close this thread too? There is no value in this.

Answer (score 6):

One answer is to use R (see the Finance taskview http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Finance.html ).  In this case it does not work like Excel (and that's a good thing).

Answer (score 5):

You can try CrossOver Office or LibreOffice/OpenOffice Calc. And let me qualify that with: Don't go down the LibreOffice road, you run in al sorts of issues such as rounding errors and that one missing function and you will not get any support from your professor.

On a personal note: During college I preferred to dual boot or use a VM.